# Javascript localStorage working in Chrome, not Safari

Tags: javascript, firebase

This code did originally work as intended, however after checking it yesterday it no longer works in Safari (it still functions normally in Chrome and Firefox).

Here is what I am trying to do:  I am declaring the variable "salonSelection" outside of the visible function then I have a click function that places a value in salonSelection. salonSelection is then put into localStorage. The click function then sends the window to a new location. This works as intended, except Safari DOES NOT pass the variable outside of the click function.

Here is the code, I commented as much as possible for the sake of readability. At the very bottom is what gives me a null value. Thanks for any help in advance:

```
    var salonSelection

// fetch a list of salons in DB
allRef.child("salons").on('child_added', function(snapshot) {

// for each group, fetch the name and print it
    var salonId = snapshot.key();
    allRef.child("salons/" + salonId + "/salonName").once('value', function(snapshot) {

        // Creates a new row for each item in table
        var newRow = $('<tr>').text('').appendTo('#searchTable');

        // Adds a cell for each salonName in row
        var nameCell = $('<td>').text(snapshot.val()).appendTo(newRow);

        // Adds an id of the salon name + 'Id' to each row
        var cellId = nameCell.attr("id", snapshot.val().replace(/\s+/g, '') + "Id")

        // Changes class of each cell
        nameCell.addClass("text-left font-w600 text-primary");

        // Passes clicked salon name to a variable for use on another page
        $('#searchTable tr td').click(function(){

            // Acquires text value of the specific td of tr
            salonSelection = $(this)[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue

            // Saves the variable to local storage
            delete localStorage.salonSelection;
            window.localStorage.salonSelection = salonSelection;

            // Sends user to new location
            window.location = 'base_pages_schedule_1.html';
        });
    });
});

// Attempting to retrieve the localStorage object, this is null in Safari only
$('#salon-name').click(function() {
    console.log(localStorage.salonSelection)
})
```

After the suggestion for using `.data()`, I added some additional code to test. The result with this is now `undefined` is being logged to console for all browsers.

```
            // Passes clicked salon name to a variable for use on another page
        $('#searchTable tr td').click(function(){

            // Acquires text value of the specific td of tr
            salonSelection = $(this).text()

            $(this).data("salonSelection", { name1: salonSelection});
            test = $(this).data("salonSelection").name1;

            // The value IS being stored and retrieved accurately here
            console.log(test)

            // Saves the variable to local storage 
            delete localStorage.salonSelection;
            window.localStorage.salonSelection = salonSelection;
            window.location = 'base_pages_schedule_1.html';
        });
    });
});

// Attempting to retrieve the .data() object, this is undefined
$('#salon-name').click(function() {
    console.log(test)
});
```

Upon closer inspection, restarting the Safari browser allows the entire function to run correctly ONLY ONCE (this is for the initial code I provided). With every time after that, the `$('#salon-name').click()` function only logs the stored element from the first run through.

Comment: Which parts of this code are relevant to the question? There are DOM manipulations, database queries, and localStorage ops. Please perform due diligence and reduce this to the minimal problem set. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [creating an mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thanks for the insight, I will be sure to read up on those before posting again!

Answer (score 0):

http://caniuse.com/#search=localstorage suggests that Safari can use localStorage, so I don't think that's it.

Debug into the click handler, and see what the value of `salonSelection` is after getting it from the td.  My guess is it's blank, yielding the value you see.

Why?  I'm guessing there's additional markup or nodes somewhere in there that make `$(this)[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue` not behave as you expect.  You might try simplifying this to `$(this).text()` and see if it gets you the data you're looking for.  If that doesn't work, try storing the value in [`$(..).data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) rather than in the visible text.

Comment: After refreshing myself on `.data()` I thought that would have worked. However, it did not. I even changed `salonSelection = $(this).text();` to avoid as much additional markup getting in the way. I will add the changed code above for reference.

Comment: What is `salonSelection` after getting the value?  Is it blank?

Comment: It's not blank. It contains the correct value, which is the value of the nameCell variable.

Comment: Then that is weird.  Sounds like the issue may be with local storage then.  Maybe try `window.localStorage.salonSelection = salonSelection || '';`